# android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TableRow

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to add row to tablelayout. But android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TableRow error's occuring.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.khash.santotootsoolol.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_result"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:text="Date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/table_header"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="Payment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/table_header"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>


            <TextView
                android:text="Remainder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/table_header"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>


            <TextView
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Interest"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/table_header"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TableLayout tableLayout = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table_result);
        TableRow tr = (TableRow)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.table_row, null);
        tableLayout.addView(tr);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);}
}
```

my custom table row is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_pay_date"
        android:text="7/31/2017"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/table_row_item"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_monthly_payment"
        android:text="13,933,700"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/table_row_item"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_remainder_payment"
        android:text="125,403,300"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/table_row_item"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_interest"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/table_row_item"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm changed linear layout and inflater but error is still occured. Or i can't inflate custom layout in table layout?

Comment: Did you try to `<incluce` the layout?

Comment: include tableLayout?

Comment: You are finding the view before setting it on the activity.

Comment: <include layout="@layout/table_layout"></include> nothing changed

Comment: Go with what @sarthakGandhi said... `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` should be before you inflate the layout. Just after `onCreate`

Comment: @sarthakGandhi when i trying to fix error i changed that.

Comment: Ok what you need to do is take the parent of the inflated view as a TableRow. And then take a linear layout inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_pay_date"
    android:text="7/31/2017"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/table_row_item"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_monthly_payment"
    android:text="13,933,700"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/table_row_item"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_remainder_payment"
    android:text="125,403,300"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/table_row_item"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_interest"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/table_row_item"/>

</TableRow>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks . R.layout.table_row  container layout is not tableRow so error is occured.